# Tips for golfing in Burlesque

Tags: code-golf, tips

This serves as a catalog for tips related to golfing in [Burlesque](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Burlesque).
Burlesque is a lazy, esoteric programming language. It's mostly used on anarchy golf while popularity on Codegolf is not as high. However, this catalog is intended to be used by people golfing on anarchy golf as well.

Please only mention tricks and not obvious shortcuts. An obvious shortcut is for example using `r\` instead of `r@\[` because the built-in `r\` is defined to be `r@\[` and is stated as such in the documentation and is thus just an obvious shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

### Using `".. .."wd` instead of `{".."".."}`

If you need a Block of Strings such as `{"abc" "def"}` it is shorter to use the *words* built-in: `"abc def"wd`.

### Using `ra` to parse *fail-safe*

`ps` will fail if the input is not properly formated or might produce unwanted results. In such cases, using `ra` is better.

```
blsq ) "5,"ra
5
blsq ) "5,"ps
{5 ,}
blsq ) "5a"ps
{ERROR: (line 1, column 3):
unexpected end of input}
blsq ) "5a"ra
5
```

### Using `,` to drop stdin

`,` is defined as a pop instruction if and only if there is exactly one element on the stack. It's used to pop STDIN from the stack when it's not needed but there (such as for example is the case on anarchy golf).

### Abusing the way `mo` is defined

`mo` is defined as `1R@\/?*` and is used to generate a Block containing multiples of N:

```
blsq ) 3mo9.+
{3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27}
```

Yet due to side effects of `?*` you can do some nasty things with it if you don't provide a number:

```
blsq ) "1"mo9.+
{"11" "21" "31" "41" "51" "61" "71" "81" "91"}

blsq ) {1 2 3 4}mo9.+
{1 4 9 16}
```